# BackgroundMode plugin for Ionic 2 is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have installed the `BackgroundMode` Plugin correctly as described in the Ionic 2 Docs.

Using the following code:

```
this.backgroundMode.on('enable').subscribe(()=>{
          console.log("BG Mode ENABLED");
          setTimeout(function(){
            try{
              console.log("BG Active"+this.backgroundMode.isActive());
            }catch(err){
              console.log(err.message);
            }
          },5000);
        });
```

Returns `BG Mode ENABLED` in the console, but the 2nd part in the timeout block returns:

`Cannot read property isActive of undefined`

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context(`this`) inside your function changes when you use the `function () {}` syntax for callbacks. Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to capture the correct context:

```
this.backgroundMode.on('enable').subscribe(()=>{
      console.log("BG Mode ENABLED");
      setTimeout(() => { // Use arrow function here
        try{
          console.log("BG Active"+this.backgroundMode.isActive());
        }catch(err){
          console.log(err.message);
        }
      },5000);
});
```

[Documentation on arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). See [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) for how it differs from `function () {}` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try it when I'm back :) just had a read of the docs though, seems like that's the issue